# How to offer (optional) notification handlers in MediatR

Tags: c#, console-application, mediatr

I am using Jimmy Bogard's [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/) library in a console app to call various SOAP end points. The app is configured and working beautifully through the magic of a few `IRequestHandler<T1, T2>` implementations.

However, in all of my command line utility calls, there are 2 flags that allow the user to save the Xml response (along with other details) to a database table and / or save a text file. I feel like this is a great opportunity for an `INotificationHandler<T>`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the workflow.

It is my understanding that once registered via IoC, they are always listening. However, (in my case) they would be dynamically set depending on the command line flags.

```cs
public class SoapRequest : IRequest<string>
{
   // lots of properties here...

   public bool SkipDatabase { get; set; }
   public string OutputFile { get; set; }
}

// in my handler
public class SoapRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<SoapRequest, string>
{

   public async Task<string> Handler(SoapRequest request, CancellationToken token)
   {
      // fetches soap data, and does other stuff here... 
      var responseXml = await _endPoint.DoStuff(request.Prop1, ...);

      if (!request.SkipDatabase)
      {
         var dbCommand = new DatabaseCommand 
         { 
            ResponseString = responseXml, 
            ... 
         };

         await _mediator.Send(dbCommand, token);
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.OutputFile))
      {
         var fileCommand = new XmlFileCommand 
         { 
            FileName = request.OutputFile, 
            Xml = responseXml, 
            ... 
         };

         await _mediator.Send(fileCommand, token);
      }

      return responseXml;
   }
}
```

### Consider The Following:

*This will save to the results to a database table*

```
> myapp fetch_users
```

*This will write the results to a text file, and **NOT** save to the database*

```
> myapp fetch_users --output-file="c:\temp\users.xml" --skip-db
```

I'm currently managing this with 2 separate `IRequest` commands / handlers, and it's starting to exude a code smell. Some of my low-level handlers are exposing higher-level properties on the request objects that don't apply. I'd like to make use of notification handlers to solve this, but only register it on demand, depending on the users CLI flags.

Since MediatR is configured in IoC at *start up*, this presents a problem for me. My concern is that if I register two notification handlers (`DatabaseNotificationHandler` and `FileSystemNotificationHandler`), they will always be listening, and I can't figure out how to get the flags into the handlers dynamically without passing them to my deepest handlers. Is there a better way?

`#WWJBD` - What would Jimmy Bogard do? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about `MediatR` so I don't really know what's possible. But, can you just... not register the handlers when configuring your IoC container? Like, presumably you're doing that in `Program.Main`. So, can you just read the command line arguments there and either register your `INotificationHandler<>` or not based on the arguments?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was actually looking for a way to do this outside of IoC since the properties could change dynamically in a higher level handler. For more information on how the workflow will go, I've posted my question (with pseudo code) to the MediatR issues here: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/490#issuecomment-581172657

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved in [jbogard/MediatR Github Issues](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/490#issuecomment-582096201).

The solution was to *NOT* nest multiple `MediatR.Send(...)` calls or even use `MediatR.Publish(...)`, but instead refactor my code to proper business logic in my main handler. My soap requests have the required properties on them that get converted to domain types, which I then use to determine how things work on each soap call (ie. database capture and Xml file serialization).

Thank you to @lilasquared for the tip.